# Remove Appendices from table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I used this code to generate appendices

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \mtcaddchapter
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} \mtcaddchapter
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\section{aaaa}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The appendices appear at the end of the table of contents

How i can remove them so they will not appear

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
```

at the very beginning of the `subappendices` environment.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \mtcaddchapter
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} \mtcaddchapter

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\section{aaaa}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If chapters, in particular thise for the appendices, are beign `\include`d, it's best to place the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
```

in the subsidiary file just before the `\chapter` command.